# PHP - Troubles using pcntl_fork with shutdown function

Tags: php, parallel-processing, command-line-interface

I had some several scripts that were running for a long time (6+ hours).
They were all containing a main loop that did it's thing, and a registered shutdown function that triggered a mysql query to announce the process as "done".

I decided to use pcntl_fork() inside these main loops, to run each round as a different process, in order to make the entire script complete faster.

It works OK, but, each child process is still registered with the shutdown function.
Therefore, each time a child process is complete it calls that mysql query and announce the script as complete.
How can I disable that shutdown function for the child processes, but keep it alive for the parent?

Sample code to understand what's going on:

- **common.php**

  ```
  register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
  function shutdown()
  {   global $objDb,$arg_id ;

         echo "\n\n Executing queue process shutdown function.";
         $objDb->query("UPDATE queue_args SET done='1' WHERE id='{$arg_id}'"); 
  }
  ```
- **loop.php**

  ```
  include('common.php');
  for ($i=1;$i<=200;$i++){    
         $pid = pcntl_fork(); 
         if (!$pid) {
             //child proccess - do something without calling the shutdown function
             posix_kill(getmypid(),9);
         } 
  }  exit(); //this is when the shutdown function should eventually be called
  ```

Thanks

Comment: You need to share your code otherwise this leads to wild guessing.

Comment: Hey, I edited the question, please review

Comment: Yes the edit makes this much more clear. You have got a design issue because you register the shutdown function regardless whether this is a parent process or a child. You need to register it *later*  or have some global variable telling about the nature (e.g. `$pid`, if it is 0 it is a child process). You can not de-register shutdown functions in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You could register the shutdown function within the if, like this:

```
if ($pid) {
    if(!$registered) {
        $registered = true;
        register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
    }
}else{
    //child proccess - do something without calling the shutdown function
    posix_kill(getmypid(),9);
}
```

Comment: The shutdown function is already defined earlier in the common.php, I can't do anything about it

Comment: @GalWeissman: Then you are lost. Change the existing code or complain. I see no other alternatives than these two.

Comment: @GalWeissman It may be possible using [override_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) but I'm not sure if that's a good idea, or if you have that extension available :)

Comment: What if I set $pid=getmypid(); in the begining of common.php, and then check inside the shutdown function if $pid>0

Comment: My mistake, it works, but I have to do something about waiting for the child processes to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You could set a flag in the child processes after forking and poll it in the shutdown function - if it's set then return early. Or store the parent pid before you fork and, inside the shutdown function, return early if that's not the current pid. Or register the function in the parent process after forking.

> if (!$pid) { posix_kill(getmypid(),9); }

This is really bad way to prevent the shutdown function from being invoked in the child process - but has all sorts of other implications - PHP won't shut down cleanly, buffers won't be flushed. Maybe you just need to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$arg_id = exec('task_which_forks.php');
exec("queue_clean_up.php $arg_id");
```